# Identify user session for dynamic client interaction between a Cloud application and an Angular/Pyramid application

Tags: cross-platform, websockets, http-request, angular, cross-browser

I’m writing a web application with an Angular client and a Pyramid/Python server. I need to dynamically interface with an external cloud application, with two requirements:

- When the end user approves an invoice in that external cloud application,
  the Angular client should automatically open in the browser and show the invoice to
  be handled (or add the invoice to a list of invoices to be handled).
- If in the meantime other invoices have been approved in the
  cloud app, by the same user or by other users, the list of
  invoices to be handled in the Angular client needs to be
  automatically updated for all users.

I think I see how to solve the latter requirement:
Upon approval of the invoice, the cloud app would send the invoice data to the Pyramid server using an HTTP PUT request. In order to avoid polling by the Angular clients, I’d use web sockets (Crossbars/Autobahn) to transfer the new invoice (or updated) invoice from the Pyramid server to all connected Angular clients. That would result in the array of invoices to be handled in the Angular clients to be automatically updated.

I’m trying to find a way to automatically start the Angular client and open the invoice page for the Cloud app user that approved that invoice.
Is there any identifier of the browser or workstation that the cloud application could include in the PUT request and that I can then use to open the Angular client for that user? Any other ways to solve this problem?

I also would like to know whether Crossbars/Autobahn is still a good choice for web sockets  (which I’ve been using 6 years ago).

Comment: Is this workflow expected to be quick enough that the end user will remain on a single page or use case in the Angular application, or do you need to implement Eventual Consistency here? Is the user expected to be some place else in your application when the notification comes back in through the web socket?

Comment: Eventual Consistency is accepable, the expectation is that data between systems become consistent after a couple of seconds. The user may or may not be in the Angular application. If not in the application it should be opended automatically with the new invoice displayed. If the user is in the application the new invoice must be added to the list of invoices to be handled (the user continues the work he/she is doing).

Comment: If the user is not "in the angular application", how will you have any connection to the web browser? And perhaps that is the heart of your question. Browsers have a [notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification), which might be useful.

Comment: Hi Greg, Thanks for you reply. That is indeed the heart of my question. Do I understand correctly that through notifications API the browser provides a unique key to the Cloud application, which is then sent to my back-end server. My back-end server uses that key to send a notification to the end-user's browser. I guess that the notification can contain a URL that points to the page in my front-end application. When the user clicks on the URL, Angular client is opened on the right page?